# Does Charm++ support device addition in Adaptive MPI?

Tags: c++, mpi, charm++

I have a bad network on which devices appear and disapper all the time (alike IoT). Does Charm++ Adaptive MPI support network resize (scale up and down)?

Answer (score 1):

Charm++ and Adaptive MPI provide support for "malleable" jobs where the set of available processors dynamically shrinks and expands over time, either because of hardware failures or because the user wants to run on a different number of cores for some reason. This is possible for 2 basic reasons:

1) The programming model is based decomposing work into logical entities (tasks) rather than physical ones (processors).

2) The runtime system takes care of location management and can migrate all tasks and their data during execution.

The key is that shrinking/expanding a job is just like dynamically load balancing from the point of view of the runtime system. So once you have written a Charm++ program that is capable of doing dynamic load balancing, you can take advantage of malleable job and automatic checkpoint/restart support. For an example of this feature, see examples/charm++/shrink_expand/ in the mainline of the Charm++ source.

Comment: Please provide at least a minimal example in the answer, not just a link or reference to external resource

Comment: You should also mention Charm++'s fault tolerance support, if those nodes drop off the network unexpectedly.